# FTP upload from html form not working

Tags: php, html

I want upload a file on a server FTP but i can't, i'v got this message:

> Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => ftp_put(fichier.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [file] => /xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.php [line] => 97 )

This is my php code:

```
<? 
if(isset($_POST['mission'])){

    $new_mission = $_FILES['newmission']['name'];

        // connect
        $ftp = ftp_connect("xxxxxxxx");
        if (!$ftp){

            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <b>Erreur !</b> Connexion échoué !
            </div>
            <?

        }else{

            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <b>Succès !</b> Connexion effectué
            </div>
            <?

            // login
            $r = ftp_login($ftp, "xxxx", "xxxxx");
            if (!$r){

                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <b>Erreur !</b> Identification échoué !
                </div>
                <?

            }else{

                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <b>Succès !</b> Identification effectué
                </div>
                <?

                // enter passive mode
                $r = ftp_pasv($ftp, true);
                if (!$r){

                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <b>Erreur !</b> Impossible de passer en FTP passif !
                    </div>
                    <?

                }else{

                    /*$liste_fichiers = ftp_nlist($ftp, '.');

                    foreach($liste_fichiers as $fichier)
                    {
                        echo $fichier. '<br>';
                    }*/

                    $old_name = "fichier.txt";
                    $new_name = "/saves/".date('d_m_Y_H_i_s').".old";

                    if(ftp_rename($ftp, $old_name, $new_name)){

                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                          <b>Succès !</b> Fichier sauvegardé et déplacé
                        </div>
                        <?

                        if(ftp_put($ftp, "./", $new_mission, FTP_BINARY))
                        {
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                              <b>Succès !</b> Nouvelle mission envoyé
                            </div>
                            <?
                        }else{
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                              <b>Erreur !</b> Impossible d'envoyer la nouvelle mission <? print_r(error_get_last()); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?
                        }

                    }else{
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                          <b>Erreur !</b> Impossible de renomer et sauvegarder le fichier !
                        </div>
                        <?
                    }
                }

            }
        }
}
?>
```

and this is my html form:

```
<form class="form" method="post" style="margin: 0; max-width: 40%;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="register-wrap">
     <h4>Mettre à jour: fichier.txt</h4>
     <input type="file" name="newmission" style="display: inline-block;" required>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="mission" ><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Mettre à jour</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Anyone can help me ?

Edit in answers

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Don't use short tags `<?` when opening PHP blocks. Use the full tag `<?php` instead. Short tags are disabled as default since  a few versions back.

Comment: Thanks. And for my error message, they have an idea ?

Comment: `$new_mission = $_FILES['newmission']['name']` only contains the original file name of the uploaded file. When you upload a file, it actually gets uploaded to a temp folder (with a temp name). To get the path to the actual uploaded file, use: `$_FILES['newmission']['tmp_name']`. Read more about file uploads in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: You should also read the manual for [ftp_put()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php). The second argument is the remote _file_, not folder.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mission'])){

    if (isset($_FILES['newmission']) && $_FILES['newmission']['error'] == 0)
    {
        // Testons si l'extension est autorisée
        mkdir('./tmp/');
        $infosfichier_r = pathinfo($_FILES['newmission']['name']);
        $extension_upload = $infosfichier_r['extension'];
        $extensions_autorisees = array('pbo');
        $file = 'HyonaRP.'.$extension_upload;

        if (in_array($extension_upload, $extensions_autorisees))
        {
            // On peut valider le fichier et le stocker définitivement
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['newmission']['tmp_name'], 'tmp/'.$file);

            // connect
            $ftp = ftp_connect("xxxxxxxx");
            if (!$ftp){

                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <b>Erreur !</b> Connexion échoué !
                </div>
                <?

            }else{

                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <b>Succès !</b> Connexion effectué
                </div>
                <?

                // login
                $r = ftp_login($ftp, "xxx", "xxx");
                if (!$r){

                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <b>Erreur !</b> Identification échoué !
                    </div>
                    <?

                }else{

                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <b>Succès !</b> Identification effectué
                    </div>
                    <?

                    // enter passive mode
                    $r = ftp_pasv($ftp, true);
                    if (!$r){

                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                          <b>Erreur !</b> Impossible de passer en FTP passif !
                        </div>
                        <?

                    }else{

                        /*$liste_fichiers = ftp_nlist($ftp, '.');

                        foreach($liste_fichiers as $fichier)
                        {
                            echo $fichier. '<br>';
                        }*/

                        $old_name = "HyonaRP.pbo";
                        $new_name = "/saves/".date('d_m_Y_H_i_s').".old";

                        if(ftp_rename($ftp, $old_name, $new_name)){

                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                              <b>Succès !</b> Fichier sauvegardé et déplacé
                            </div>
                            <?
                            $new_mission = "./tmp/HyonaRP.pbo";
                            if(ftp_put($ftp, "./HyonaRP", $new_mission, FTP_ASCII))
                            {
                                /* Supperssion des fichiers tmp */
                                $path = "./tmp/";
                                $rep=opendir($path);

                                while($files = readdir($rep)){
                                    if($files != '..' && $files !='.' && $files !='' && $files!='.htaccess'){
                                        unlink($path.$file);
                                    }
                                }
                                rmdir('./tmp/');

                                ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                  <b>Succès !</b> Nouvelle mission envoyé 
                                </div>
                                <?
                            }else{
                                ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                  <b>Erreur !</b> Impossible d'envoyer la nouvelle mission <? print_r(error_get_last()); ?>
                                </div>
                                <?
                            }

                        }else{
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                              <b>Erreur !</b> Impossible de renomer et sauvegarder le fichier !
                            </div>
                            <?
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }else{
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <b>Erreur!</b> Les extentions autorisés sont: pdf:
            </div>  
            <?php
         }
    }else{
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable" style="margin: 0;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <b>Erreur!</b> Veuillez joindre les documents demandés.
        </div>  
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: the ftp server are on windows server using Filezila. The account of ftp login are maked directly in the great directory